# TFS Lab Center Environments stuck in "Preparing"

Tags: azure-devops, lab-management

I have created an environment in Lab Center. I have installed a TestController that uses the DefaultCollection from my Visual Studio Team Services account.

The environment is now stuck in "Preparing". I can't find how to delete the environment. The tfsconfig lab /delete account only applies to SCVMM and I'm using standard environments without SCVMM.

Does anyone know how to delete an environment from the Visual Studio Team Services? Normally I would manually edit the database but that's not possible with Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: Lab Environments are no longer supported on VSTS and have been replaced by new agent infrastructures and machine groups. Voting to close.